# Is there currently a way to develop a window desktop program via flutter? if yes, how?

Tags: flutter

I hope to develop a windows desktop program through flutter, but I have not found any practical and useful method articles, find a video to run the program through the launcher, but the request is mac os, so how to use flutter-desktop-embedding?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the page describing the current state of Flutter for Desktop: https://flutter.dev/desktop. If you are trying to make a production application, rather than experiment with early stages, it's definitely not ready yet.

If you do want to experiment, this page has the current instructions: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/README.md#running-a-project